# How can I substitute a variable whose value begins with a minus sign?

Tags: bash, awk

I need to get the value of xmin:

```
grep 'x_min ' filename | awk '{print $4}'
```

which gives

```
-4.0
```

But I need to save this as a variable, which breaks

```
xmin=${grep 'x_min ' in.sparta | awk '{print $4}'}
```

```
bash: ${grep 'x_min ' in.sparta | awk '{print $4}'}: bad substitution
```

But why??

```
x=-4.0
echo $x
```

```
-4.0
```

I am really curious, there must be a simple way! Can you please tell me?

Comment: probably because `{` and `(` are not the same? see `LESS=+/Command\ Substitution man bash` or this [online-manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

Comment: https://shellcheck.net is your friend!!!

Comment: `grep | awk` is an anti-pattern.  `grep foo | awk '{...}'` is better written `awk '/foo/{...}'`.

Comment: *Thank you Jetchisel I appreciate that shellcheck.net very much! Thank you William for the awk pattern, indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't try to invent things that not exists**:

instead of:

```
xmin=${grep 'x_min ' in.sparta | awk '{print $4}'}
```

use

```
xmin=$(grep 'x_min ' in.sparta | awk '{print $4}') 
#     ^                                          ^
```

or even shorter/better:

```
xmin=$(awk '/x_min /{print $4}' in.sparta)
```